# How to get rid of commit messages in git but keep the commit

Tags: git

I want to get rid of the commit messages in a way that they don't show up when someone gitk's it but want to keep the commits, see example screenshot.[image]

the one on top is showing all the commits and messages for the branch develop

and at the bottom marking it is showing messages of commit for the branch bgColorPausFunc

I want just the first and last message stays with all commit dad of all the intermediate commits are preserved but messages and commit can be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can squash all the commits into a single one. You can use git rebase -i (interactive) for that:

```
 git rebase --interactive
```

The editor will open, change "pick" to "squash" for all except the last one. Then save and edit the commit message.

This will rewrite your history.

Here is a nice post explaining it in detail: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html